# Is there a way to erase contents of the bsModal() window when Close button is pushed?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using bsModal() window from the ShinyBS package in one of my Shiny Apps. Whenever the user opens the modal window for the second time, the contents of the window from the first opening remain on the screen until the new content loads. Which is not ideal. Is there a way to delete the contents of the bsModal() window once it is closed? I do not want the older content to appear in the window once it is reopened. Subsequently, maybe there is a way to clean up the bsModal() window before opening?

I wasn't able to find any solution for this

Here is some example (not my) code of an app that can be also accessed through:
library(shinyBS)
bsExample("Modals")

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
 fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       sliderInput("bins",
                   "Number of bins:",
                   min = 1,
                   max = 50,
                   value = 30),
       actionButton("tabBut", "View Table")
     ),

     mainPanel(
       plotOutput("distPlot"),
       bsModal("modalExample", "Data Table", "tabBut", size = "large",
         dataTableOutput("distTable"))
     )
   )
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
shinyServer(
 function(input, output, session) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

     x    <- faithful[, 2]
     bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

     # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
     hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

   })

   output$distTable <- renderDataTable({

     x    <- faithful[, 2]
     bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

     # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
     tab <- hist(x, breaks = bins, plot = FALSE)
     tab$breaks <- sapply(seq(length(tab$breaks) - 1), function(i) {
       paste0(signif(tab$breaks[i], 3), "-", signif(tab$breaks[i+1], 3))
     })
     tab <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, tab))
     colnames(tab) <- c("Bins", "Counts", "Density")
     return(tab[, 1:3])

   }, options = list(pageLength=10))

 }
)
```

Comment: take a look here: https://github.com/ebailey78/shinyBS/issues/39

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly what I was looking for.